# I want to change "," for "." in the priceString

Tags: android

Working on Android app in the Android Studio

But there is a pop-up window on replaceAll that says: "Result of this will be ignored"

```
 String priceString = mPriceEditText.getText().toString().trim();

if(priceString.contains(",")){
    priceString.replaceAll(",",".");
}
```

How could I fix this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are unmutable in Java, therefore `priceString.replaceAll(",",".")` cannot change `priceString`. Instead it returns a new string that you ignore.

You need to assign the returned string to something, e.g.:

```
priceString = priceString.replaceAll(",",".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `priceString.replace(",",".")` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try above code

```
String priceString = mPriceEditText.getText().toString().trim();
final String newPriceString;

  if(priceString.contains(",")){
      newPriceString = priceString.replaceAll(",",".");
  }
```